# C# - Reshape Array & change type in place

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, reshape, unsafe

I read a huge image (e.g. 1.800MP @ 16 bit per pixel) from disk. `Magick.Net` provides me with a 1D-Byte array, so every pixel is 2 elements in the array. I need to have a 2d array of `ushort` for processing.

Needless to say, `BlockCopy` and alike are forbidden - doubling the memory usage is not an option.

The data already has the right order in memory, I just need to "cast" the array from `byte[]` to `ushort[,]` somehow.

So basically, I am looking for a function that does this:

```
ushort[,] convertByteToUshort(byte[] arr, int width, int height)
```

I know the width & height of the image (and thus, 2d array), and I guess I will need to use `unsafe` code and `fixed` for the pointers. But I have no idea how to transform the reference to a true `ushort[,]`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to convert it? Why not do an indexer or even a function to get the ushort at x,y?

Comment: You have `byte[,]` in the example. Shouldn't it be `byte[]`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, thank you. Fixed it, it should of course be `byte[]`

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        static ushort[] convertByteToUshort(byte[] arr)
        {
            List<ushort> data = new List<ushort>();

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i = +2)
            {
                data.Add((ushort)((arr[i] << 8) | arr[i + 1]));
            }
            return data.ToArray();
        }
```

---

Here is a clever trick I found about a month ago

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ByteShort byteShort = new ByteShort();
            byteShort.bytes = new byte[100];
            byteShort.shorts = new short[50];
            for (int i = 0; i < byteShort.bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                byteShort.bytes[i] = (byte)i;
            }

            short[] data = byteShort.shorts;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct ByteShort
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public byte[] bytes;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public short[] shorts;
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't this also copy the data, so double the memory consumption? Furthermore, it is also just a 1D list - it should be `ushort[ , ]`

Comment: Why is it two dimensional?  Yes it uses double memory.  Look at my trick that I just posted to use same memory.